# KnockoutJS - Data binding error

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

I'm new to `KnockoutJS`, I'm using it for a school project which is based on a movie API from where I get data into UI.

This is my **app.js** where all the javascript code is:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.movies = ko.observableArray;
    self.error = ko.observable;

    var moviesUri = '/api/movies/';

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error('');
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function getAllMovies() {
        ajaxHelper(moviesUri, 'GET').done(function(data) {
            self.movies(data);
        });
    }

    getAllMovies();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And this is my index.html where the data is displayed:

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
}

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Movie Database API</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Movies</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: movies">
                    <li>
                        <!--<strong>
                            <span data-bind="text: DirectorName"></span>
                        </strong>:--> <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
                        <small>
                            <a href="#">Details</a>
                        </small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: error">
            <p data-bind="text: error"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- TODO: Movie details -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- TODO: Add new movie -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I checked the code and it seems fine, but when I run my application I get into console this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function
>   (){return movies }" Message: Unable to process binding "text: function
>   (){return Title }" Message: Title is not defined

Can someone point me to the right direction and tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis in your observables declarations:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.movies = ko.observableArray();
                                  //^^ here
    self.error = ko.observable();
                            //^^ here
    //...
}
```

Besides, beware that the properties of your `observableArray` will not be made observables by default (you might want to look into the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)).